# Surface Integral - parametric expression

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Good morning. I would please like to ask for your contribution to the following problem:

Let the surface $S$ that surrounds the following three dimensional domain:
$$
\{x^2+y^2≤4,0\le z\le1\}\text{ in }\Bbb R^3 
$$
and let $F=(x, - y, z^2-1)$.
I would like to calculate the surface integral of  $F$. I am fully aware of the steps to be followed, but I have found difficulty in expressing the domain above in a parametric way.

I would appreciate for your guidance. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What specifically have you had trouble with? Edit your post to include these details

Answer (score 0):

How about putting
$$ x = r \cos \theta, \ y = r \sin \theta, \ z = z,$$
where
$$ 0 \leq r \leq 2, \ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi, \ 0 \leq z \leq 1?$$

Won't that do the job for you?

Comment: Thank you very much. Will I compute the integral only for the surface of cylinder, or for each cylinder' s base as well, using the vertical vectors (0,0, 1) and (0,0,0,-1)?

Comment: @kostas why bring in $(0, 0, -1)$?